# How can I suppress specific flycheck messages in sh-mode?

Tags: flycheck, bash

In `sh-mode` I am getting following flycheck-error message:

```bash
File   Line [v]ColLevel   ID     Message (Checker)
config.sh  2     error           Syntax error: "(" unexpected (sh-posix-dash)
```

for the following line:
`strings=("hello" "world")` . But this is actually a valid expression in `bash`.

complete file:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

strings=("hello" "world")
```

`init.el` file has following lines, [reference](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2541/18414):

> ```lisp
> (define-derived-mode my-cfg-mode sh-mode "My CFg Mode"
>  "A mode for my CFg files."
>  (sh-set-shell "bash"))
> ```

Is it possible to suppress this warning message?

Comment: Can't reproduce it: `flycheck` is happy with it. What does the complete file look like? Is there a shebang on line 1? And what is `sh-posix-dash`?

Comment: @NickD `sh-posix-dash` is one of the shell checkers in `flycheck`

Comment: @alper if you're using bash, use the bash checker.

Comment: @NickD Yes sir there is `#!/bin/bash` line (updated on my question). `flycheck-sh-posix-dash-executable` is set to `nil`

Comment: @nega How can I set `bash checker` from the init.el file?

Comment: I have no idea where did `sh-posix-dash` come from, `(with-eval-after-load 'flycheck
  (setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers '(sh-posix-dash)))` solved the problem

Comment: @alper great! feel free to post that as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As checker `sh-posix-dash` was enabled. When I add following lines into my `init.el` file the problem is solved.

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'flycheck   
    (setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers '(sh-posix-dash)))
```

---

As @Ian mention core cause was due to following lines, hence also removing those lines from my `init.el` file was also resolved the conflict:

> ```bash
> (define-derived-mode my-cfg-mode sh-mode "My CFg Mode"
> "A mode for my CFg files."
> (sh-set-shell "bash"))
> ```

Comment: I think you have a chicken-egg problem: why did you added those
three lines in your ```init.el``` file? You did not copied the whole
example, which defines a derived mode for a ```.cfg``` file, while your
file is still a ```.sh``` file, so you created yourself a problem. Try to
remove those lines, you do not need them to have correct
behavior. Neither to disable a checker.

Comment: @Ian Honestly I couldn't remember why I added those three lines(indicated in my question) in my `init.el` file :-( I was thinking they are required for something I was using but instead they were causing conflict like you mentioned. I updated my answer, please feel free to edit